# Has anyone successfully built C# version of WFDB using SWIG wrappers from Physionet.org?

Tags: c#, wrapper, swig

I am trying to build a C# wrapper for latest [WFDB software](https://physionet.org/content/wfdb/10.6.2/) from physionet.org using [SWIG wrappers published in the same location](https://physionet.org/content/wfdb-swig/1.0.0/), and I cant seem to be able to do so.  I have made a bunch of fixes so far, which gets me further in the process but it keeps failing in different places.  Based on some of the fixes I had to do so far, it seems that C# SWIG wrappers published are not correct or out of date.   Rather than explaining each failure, I was wondering if anyone got the SWIG wrappers working correctly, and willing to share correct version.

PS: I am aware of https://github.com/BoutemineOualid/WfdbCsharpWrapper, however the wfdb version it uses is very much out of date.

Comment: Did you try and file and issue to request for upgrading the Wfdb version in use (Or support thereof)? Maybe the devs are already working on it? I guess that knowledge would affect your assessment of how to proceed, no?

Comment: @fildor: I did email some persons whose names are associated with these wrappers, however i didn't get any response.